# search for matching values in two arrays with repeated values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
a = [2,2,3,0,6]
b = [6,3,2,2,0]
```

I am trying use for loop to match values and get the index of a in a new array c. How can we do this? Notice that there are multiple values which match and so I think the previous match must be skipped.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: `a.map(function(item){
return b.indexOf(item);
})`

Comment: ans wanted is: c = [4, 2, 0, 1, 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I Understand, You can try this:

```
var a = [2,2,3,0,6];
var b = [6,3,2,2,0];

var c = new Array();

for(i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
    {  
        if(b[i] === a[j] && c.indexOf(j) < 0)
        {
             c.push(j);
             break;
        }
    }
}

console.log(c); // [4, 2, 0, 1, 3]
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/3oeLz3zu/)

Comment: the answer i was looking for is: c = [4, 2, 0, 1, 3]

Comment: thanks, the answer is correct but it shows nothing in fiddle and also in my editor

Comment: @ubuntuser, check the browser console.

Answer (score 1):

This is a proposal which respects the last index and looks further.

> How it works:
>
> It uses [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for iterating array `b` with a callback. map gets an own `this` space with an really empty object `Object.create(null)`.
>
> The callback has on parameter `bb` which is one element of `b.
>
> Next is to find the element is in array `a` with a [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and a `fromIndex`, based on the former searches. The former index is stored in the `this` object, as long as the result is not `-1`, because this would reset the `fromIndex` to zero.
>
> If there is no `this[bb]` or a falsy value of `this[bb]` take zero as `fromIndex`.
>
> Later, a found `index` is incremented and stored in `this[bb]`.
>
> At least, the index is returned.

```js
var a = [2, 2, 3, 0, 6],
    b = [6, 3, 2, 2, 0],
    c = b.map(function (bb) {
        var index = a.indexOf(bb, this[bb] || 0);
        if (index !== -1) {
            this[bb] = index + 1;
        }    
        return index;
    }, Object.create(null));

console.log(c);
```

Another solution could be first generate an object with all indices of `a` and use it in the iteration of `b` for returning the indices.

The example is a bit extended, to show what happen if there is no more than two indices (2) and one without being in `a` (7).

> The content of aObj with all indices of `a`:
>
> ```
> {
>     "0": [3],
>     "2": [0, 1],
>     "3": [2],
>     "6": [4]
> }
> ```

```js
var a = [2, 2, 3, 0, 6],
    b = [6, 3, 2, 2, 0, 7, 2],
    aObj = Object.create(null),
    c;

a.forEach(function (aa, i) {
    aObj[aa] = aObj[aa] || [];
    aObj[aa].push(i);
});
c = b.map(function (bb) {
    return aObj[bb] && aObj[bb].length ? aObj[bb].shift() : -1;
});

console.log(c);
```

Comment: the ans is what I was looking for but it isn't working somehow in my editor. something i must add? like other functions or something like that?? could you simplify the meaning of this code or explain a bit?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct.

```
let c = a.map(i => b.indexOf(i))
```

or

```
var c = a.map(function(i) { return b.indexOf(i); });
```

Comment: Please provide a ES5 answer, since this question isn't tagged with ES6.

Answer (score 0):

loop `.map` function and check same value by `indexOf`

> indexOf will return a number,representing the position where the specified search value occurs for the first time, or -1 if it never occurs

```
var arr = [];    
a.map(function(v){      
    if(b.indexOf(v) > -1){
        arr.push(v);
    }
});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: as i understood this gives the same array a: arr = c = [2,2,3,0,6], I was looking for c:  [4, 2, 0, 1, 3]

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
var a = [2,2,3,0,6];
var b = [6,3,2,2,0];

var arrayLength_a = a.length;
var arrayLength_b = b.length;
var new_array=[];

 for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength_a; i++)
 {
    for (var j = 0; j < arrayLength_b; j++) 
    {
       if (a[i] == b[j]) 
       {
          if(new_array.indexOf(a[i]) === -1)
          {  
             new_array.push(a[i]);
          }
       }     
    }
 }
```